# Como apagar uma foto da galeria em Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Tenho um código onde estou usando minha câmera para tirar uma foto, em seguida a coloco em um *ImageView*, apenas para visualização, pois ela é salva em seguida no meu *SQLite*. Gostaria de saber, como faço para excluir esta foto da galeria, uma vez que ela já está no banco de dados.

Este é meu código, aqui estou abrindo a câmera e tirando a foto.

```
private void tirarFoto() {
    Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (it.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
         startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Aqui estou pegando a imagem tirada e colocando no ImageView

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
      Bitmap imagem = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
      imgEntrada.setImageBitmap(imagem);
   }
}
```